# script to su with password in script without root

Tags: linux, su

I have scripted a process that involves updating symbolic links on files located on 3 different machines. On those machines exists 4 users each, who each need to have these links updated.

Using su, is there a way to pass the password argument to the command on a single line, without invoking sudo as the users will not have admin rights?

My only alternative solution at this point is to ssh around, however I would like to be able to do this without hardcoding in a bunch of hosts/ips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pipe the password to su like this:

```
echo pa$$w0rd | su -c whoami user_1
```

Comment: Getting "Standard in must be a tty" error

Comment: Are you using ssh? Try the -t option to ssh.

Comment: @KevinVW, I don't see -t as option in su.

Comment: The -t is for ssh, not su. If forces a pseudo-tty so that su can read the password from stdin.

Comment: I am not getting a “standard in must be a tty” from `su` itself, it simply takes the password. It might be coming from the command being executed. That can't easily be made interactive, because it gets the now exhausted standard output of echo on its input.

Comment: When I try this it appears that the password is being entered but the user_1 doesn't get activated. How do I debug?